# R: how to create and address columns of a data.table inside a function

Tags: r, data.table

I want to write a function within which I build several new columns. I have some problems in adressing and naming the columns of a `data.table` inside a function. Say I have:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(iris)
```

and say I am interested in creating new variables in the same way for different colums (lets say `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width` and `Petal.Length`). I want to have a function which sums all observations by species in a new colum and then takes the ratio of each observation of `Petal.Width` over this sum. I have a working example if I specify the name of the columns:

```
thisworks <- function(a){
DT[,named_column1:=sum(eval(a),na.rm=T),by=Species]
DT[,named_column2:=named_column1/Petal.Width]
DT
}
DT <- thisworks(DT[,Sepal.Length])
```

However, if I want to do this for other variables (`Sepal.Width` and `Petal.Length`, resulting in a total of 6 new columns), I would like to assing a column name based on that. My non-working attempt:

```
thisdoesntwork <- function(b){
name1 <- paste0("total_",names(b))
#here, I don't know how to get the name of the column
DT[,assign(name1,sum(eval(column_of_interest),na.rm=T)),by=Species]
name2 <- paste0("ratio_",names(b))
DT[,assign(name2,named_column1/Petal.Width)]
DT
}

for (i in c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length"){
# I know I know, loops are evil. However, data.table is fast so i dont mind
DT <- thisdoesntwork(DT[,i,with=F])
}
```

General hints are also very much appreciated. Would it be wiser to build two functions, for example, one for each task? Or should I write the whole function inside one big `data.table` filter? I think that could also work, no?

**Edit: Second Case: Create two new variables using two different columns each**

(this is answered in Rolands Edit)

Say I want to have `ratio_Length=Sepal.Length/Petal.Length` and `ratio_Width=Sepal.Width/Petal.Width`. Why does this not work?:

```
DT <- as.data.table(iris)

myfun <- function(d,variables){
d[, paste0("ratio_",substr(variables,7,99)) := 
mapply(.SD, function(x) x / mget(paste0("Petal.",substr(variables,7,99))),
.SDcols = variables)]
d[]
}
DT <- myfun(DT,c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width"))
```

Comment: Do you want to have a function that take a data.table or is it okay to pass the variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason to assign the result of the function. `:=` assigns by reference anyway. If you want to make a copy of the data.table, you need to make an explicit `copy` in the beginning of your function.

You can use `.SD` and `.SDcols`. See the [data.table vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) for details.

```
thisworks <- function(d, cols){
  d[, paste0(cols, 1) := lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by=Species, .SDcols = cols]
  d[, paste0(cols, 2) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x / d[["Petal.Width"]]), 
     .SDcols = paste0(cols, 1)]
  d[]
}
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(iris)
thisworks(DT, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length"))
print(DT)
```

**Edit regarding your follow-up question:**

```
myfun <- function(d,variables){
  d[, gsub(".*\\.", "Ratio.", variables) := 
      Map("/", mget(variables), mget(gsub(".*\\.", "Petal.", variables)))] 
#might be more efficient to do 
#Map(function(x, y) get(x)/get(y), variables, gsub(".*\\.", "Petal.", variables))
#do some benchmarks
  d[]
}
myfun(DT,c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width"))
```

And I can only reiterate: Do not assign when you call the function. The data.table passed to it is changed by reference.

For users unfamiliar with the first argument of `gsub()` above, please refer to `?regex` for help.

Comment: very helpful post, thank you! For others: its in the vignettes under reference semantics point 2.e

Comment: could I replace d[["Petal.Width"]] with a second character vector of columns if I want to divide the three variables by different columns?

Comment: @PeterPan I think I would use `mapply` with `mget` then.

Comment: "@Roland I tried that in my edit but somehow got it wrong. Can you see where the error is?

Comment: I've added an example. PS: Please don't turn this into a chameleon question. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: wow, thanks! I didnt know Map. You're right about assigning, sorry.

Comment: should I make two questions out of it?

Comment: No, leave it now. But next time you should.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114862/discussion-between-peter-pan-and-roland).

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the first part of the question I came up with this.  It's closer to the author's own attempt at a solution and I personally prefer the syntax. It uses a for loop, but the author says he doesn't mind that.

```
library(data.table)
thisworks <- function(dat,var){
  name1 <- paste0("total.",var)
  name2 <- paste0("ratio.",var)
  DT[,c(name1) := sum(eval(dat[,var,with=F]),na.rm=T),by=Species][,c(name2) := DT[,name1,with=F]/Petal.Width]
}

DT <- as.data.table(iris)
cols <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")
for (i in 1:length(cols)){
thisworks(DT,cols[i])
}
```